# How to get onPress event from ScrollView Component in React Native

Tags: ios, scrollview, react-native

I am new to [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). I have an app with a [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) component and several custom components inside it. I would like to trigger an onPressOut event from the ScrollView, so that when the user scrolls, and releases, the child components inside the ScrollView update their states. But, the ScrollView documentation does not include any press events: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html

Other things I tried:

- I tried wrapping the scrollview inside a [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#content) component, when I do this, I get an error as soon as I try to scroll:

> 2015-10-26 11:59:13.849
>   [error][tid:com.facebook.React.ShadowQueue][RCTModuleMethod.m:60]
>   Argument 0 (NSNumber) of RCTUIManager.measure must not be null
>       2015-10-26 11:59:13.850 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.ShadowQueue][RCTModuleMethod.m:60]
>   Argument 0 () of RCTUIManager.measure could not be processed.
>   Aborting method call.

No idea what that means...
Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<View ref="theWrapperView" style={styles.theWrapperView}>
            <ScrollView 
                onScroll={this.onScroll.bind(this)}
                onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollAnimationEnd.bind(this)}

                style={styles.scrollView}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContentContainer}

                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
                scrollEventThrottle={10}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                horizontal={true}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                snapToAlignment={'center'}
                snapToInterval={20}
                zoomScale={1.5}
                centerContent = {true}

            >
                {cards}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

When I change the View element to a TouchableWithoutFeedback element is when I get the error.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out when the scrolling ends? Scroll View dispatches other types of events that might be useful for you.. Just listening to an onScroll and doing some math with scrolling offsets even might even be enough

Comment: @WillSheppard I added my code, hope that helps.

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven I would like to know specifically when the user "releases" the scroll view (ie onPress or onPressOut). The onScroll and onScrollEnd events are not necessarily helpful to me because I have pagination enabled, so when the user release the scroll view, it locks into place for the nearest page, and the onScrollEnd event does not fire until that scrolling animation finishes, which happens a second after the user releases the ScrollView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured this out after investigating the React Native source code: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder.js

As it turns out there are actually a number of other events available via the ScrollResponder mixin, that are not mentioned in the online documentation. It is not necessary to include the mixin to access these events, since they are already part of the ScrollView component. The one that was useful for me was onResponderRelease, which fires when you release the ScrollView, like so:

```
<View ref="theWrapperView" style={styles.theWrapperView}>
            <ScrollView 
                onScroll={this.onScroll.bind(this)}
                onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollAnimationEnd.bind(this)}
                onResponderRelease = {this.onResponderReleaseHandler.bind(this)}
            >
                {cards}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

and in the class define a handler:

```
onResponderRelease(){
//do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
onTouchEnd will help you to get this
```

```js
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 22, top: -16 }}
                    onTouchEnd={(e) => {
                      //Here define your ScrollView Press Event
                    }}
  >
     {this.props.children}
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, exactly what I was looking for, crazy that it's not mentioned in the docs.